# Mongoose - Count only above a certain value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose, and I'm wondering how you would do the SQL equivalent of this in mongoose!

`SELECT COUNT(balance FROM users WHERE balance > 1;` (or something very close to that)

I can't see anywhere around the .count documentation that it would allow this, or if it does how exactly!

What I'm trying to do is get some stats for my site, so counting is quite important :3

If anyone can shed some light it would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to filter documents by a condition and use `count` on that:

```
db.collection.find({
  "balance": {
    $gt: 1
  }
}).count()
```

you can also do this by using `count` alone:

```
db.collection.count({
  "balance": {
    $gt: 2
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have field called `likes`

There could be a chance that this field may not exist or may have values.

1. `$exists` can be used to check existence.
2. To sum likes greater than 5,, you should filter in `$match` and use `$sum` to count the total likes.

   ```
   db.students.aggregate([
   {
     $match: { $likes : {$gt : 3}} 
   }, 
   {
    $project: {count:{$sum:$likes}} 
    } 
   ]);
   ```
3. If you just want to count the docs whose like is greater than 3, you need to use $count.